# How do I define a member inside a on_raw_reaction_remove()?

Tags: discord.py

I tried to write a code that will remove a role from a member when a certain reaction is added. My code works fine until the end, where the role is removed from the member, where an "Attribute error" pops up; "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'"

Here's my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    await client.wait_until_ready()

    guild = await client.fetch_guild(payload.guild_id)
    member = get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)

    if payload.message_id == id:
        if payload.emoji.name == "a":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = "a")
        elif payload.emoji.name == "b":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = "b")           
        await member.remove_roles(role)
```

My guess is that i'm defining member the wrong way, but I have no idea how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

In this situation `client.get_user()` works better.

Here is the fixed code

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    await client.wait_until_ready()

    guild = await client.fetch_guild(payload.guild_id)
    member = client.get_user(id=payload.user_id)

    if payload.message_id == id:
        if payload.emoji.name == "a":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = "a")
        elif payload.emoji.name == "b":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = "b")           
        await member.remove_roles(role)
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Sadly, no, the same problem keeps displaying up; "AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'".

Comment: hmmm, maybe you should try client.get_member()

Comment: "AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'get_member'" Still doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: I know at this point I'm just guessing without knowing, but guild.get_member(payload.user_id) should definetely work. Sorry for my incredible stupidity

Answer (score 0):

The main reason behind this is `payload.member` is `None` when using `on_raw_reaction_remove`.
This is actually because discord does not send this data, so discord.py has it as `None`.
Source-https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5871

To work around this, you get the guild object in question, then grab the member object from the guild.
The payload does not have the guild object either, so we have to get that as well.

What I did is I actually created the member object and tacked it onto the payload manually in the case of `on_raw_reaction_remove`.
This way both `on_raw_reaction_add` and `on_raw_reaction_remove` have the same payload for my final processing.

```py
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):    
  guild = self.get_guild(payload.guild_id)  #Self here is Client/Bot
  member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
  payload.member = member
  await reaction_role(payload, remove=True)
```

Furthermore, this requires the privileged members intent. To enable it, log back into the developer portal and look for the privileged intents > member intent, then tick the slider to on.

```
intent = discord.Intents.default()
intent.members = True
```

The intent needs to be passed to the client, or bot wrapper if using the bot extension.

```
commands.Bot.__init__(self, <...>, intents=intent)
```